# changing cordinates button and edittext at xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

I am new at XML and trying to develop an android XML file. The problem here is that I can't move a button from somewhere else. Or an edittext neither, although I tried `android:layout_x="50dp"` or `android:layout_y="50dp"`. How can I move this button and edittext to somewhere else?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/yeni">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" android:text="">



        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="50dp"
             android:layout_y="50dp"
            android:text="YAP" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:gravity="<someOption>"` and `android:layout_gravity="<someOption>"` for align widgets.

But for more complex control i recommend to you use `<RelativeLayout>` that offers more complex work with aligment of widgets.